How to transfer data from one origin to another in React
I have two environments UAT and PROD , I want to transfer data from one environment to another.
My data contains xml file and one object containing some information
data = {xml , flowData:{flowName}}
I am on some page on UAT env , lets say Diagram Page from there I send the data and receiving end is my login page of  PROD env.
Note:- Both the environments have the same code , deployed on different env UAT and PROD
Issue is that not getting data on receiver side. When runs from local to local it is working fine
But from UAT to PROD or lets say from different origin domain to another it is not working
Diagram Page i have a function as below :-   (Sender Side)
Explanation:-
DataToSend is the data that we send to another env.
Firstly we open AnotherEnvWindow  using window.open and then post the message and data is send along with it
const redirectToAnotherEnvBuilder = async (option) => {
    // check if any option is selected
    if (Object.keys(option).length) {
      // Specify the URL of the application you want to redirect to
      const url = `${option?.url}/#/login`;
      // need origin to send data to another application
      const builderEnvUrlOrigin = AppUtil.getOriginFromUrl(option?.url);

      const flowInfo = {};
      const basicFlowInfo = FlowService.getBasicFlowInfo();
      const currentUser = UserService.getCurrentUser();
      flowInfo.flowType = FLOW_STATUS.DRAFT;
      flowInfo.businessCode = basicFlowInfo.businessCode;
      flowInfo.flowName = basicFlowInfo.flowName;
      flowInfo.flowTypeId = basicFlowInfo.flowTypeId;
      flowInfo.email = currentUser?.email;
      flowInfo.chatFlowId = selectedFlowTypeInfo?.chatFlowId || "";

      // Convert flowInfo properties to strings
      const flowInfoStringified = Object.entries(flowInfo)
        .map(([key, value]) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
        .join('&');

      const diagramXml = await DiagramService.getCurrentDiagramXml();

      // Data to be sent as query parameters
      const dataToSend = {
        flowData: flowInfoStringified,
        xml: diagramXml,
        messageType: REDIRECTED_FLOW.MESSAGE_TYPE,
      };

      // Open the URL in a new tab
      const AnotherEnvWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
      AnotherEnvWindow.onload = () => {
        // Post the data to the another Env builder window in new tab
        AnotherEnvWindow.postMessage(dataToSend, builderEnvUrlOrigin);
      };
    }
  };

Login Page i am having function below (Receiver Side)
Explanation:-
SenderOrigin = origin from where data is coming
it is then compared with event.origin as we listen to the event on login page of another env.
messageType is the unique message that comes from sender side to ensure that it is from trusted source
All the data is then set inside the useStates and everything is done.
const handleRedirectedXml = () => {
    // Listen for messages from the another env builder
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      //check the unique messageType to ensure that it is from correct origin
      const messageType = event.data?.messageType;
      // get the current environment on which user is
      const currentEnv = `${envConfig.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT}`;
      // need to check from which env data is coming
      const senderOrigin = AppUtil.getSendersOrigin(currentEnv);
      if (event.origin === senderOrigin && messageType === REDIRECTED_FLOW.MESSAGE_TYPE) {
        const receivedData = event.data;
        // Handle the received data as needed
        let flowData = receivedData?.flowData || {};
        const xml = receivedData?.xml || "";
        const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(flowData);
        // Convert the URLSearchParams object to an object
        flowData = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
        setFlowInfo(flowData);
        setRedirectedXml(xml);
        if (Object.keys(flowData).length && xml) {
          setUiState({ ...uiState, isRedirection: true });
        }
      }
    });
  }

